# Ordernar select exibindo algo no final após a ordenação

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

Tenho uma tabela chamada `Tabela1` e outra chamada `Tabela2`:

```
Tabela 1             Tabela2
Indice, pessoa_id    sts, pessoa_id
```

O índice vai de 0 a 10, e `sts` pode ser `ON-LINE`, `OFF-LINE` OU `ON-LINE-PAUSADO`.

Gostaria que quando eu desse o `select`, voltassem ordenados, mas se alguma dessas pessoas estivem com o `sts` igual a 'on-line-pausado', viessem no final do `select`.

Exemplo:

```
indice, pessoa_id, sts
4     , 2        , 'ON-LINE'
5     , 2        , 'ON-LINE'
6     , 2        , 'ON-LINE'
8     , 2        , 'ON-LINE'
1     , 2        , 'ON-LINE-PAUSADO'
2     , 2        , 'ON-LINE-PAUSADO'
```

Comment: Assim fica mais claro: http://prntscr.com/mn5fr8

Comment: Mas `ON-LINE` também está sendo apresentado no seu exemplo... Não entendi o que você deseja fazer. Se for `ON-LINE-PAUSADO` precisa mostrar, caso não seja não mostra nada?

Comment: Deu certo gente, obrigado pelo tempo de vocês, abraço :D https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXNEr.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa ordenar pelo status e depois pela coluna índice de forma decrescente.

Sua consulta ficaria da seguinte maneira:

```
SELECT
    t1.indice,
    t1.pessoa_id,
    t2.sts
FROM
    tabela1 t1
INNER JOIN tabela2 t2 ON t1.pessoa_id = t2.pessoa_id
ORDER BY
    t2.sts, t1.Indice DESC
```

Esta forma dará certo pois o nome dos seus status estão em ordem alfabética, contudo, caso você possua mais status, você pode criar uma coluna nova e ordenar por ela, adicionando um inteiro na ordem dos status que deseja retornar (1, 2, 3...).

Exemplo:

```
ALTER TABLE tabela2
ADD COLUMN ordem_status INT
```

E na mesma consulta acima, você ordenará por essa nova coluna, ficando:

```
ORDER BY t2.ordem_status, t1.Indice DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Algo não deve estar bem na sua definição de tabelas, porque na `Tabela 2` deve estar a coluna `Indice`, caso contrário ligando uma com a outra o resultado não iria ser correto.

---

Partindo do princípio que na `Tabela 2` existe a coluna `Indice`, a seguinte consulta devolve-lhe o que pretende:

```
SELECT      T1.pessoa_id
        ,   T2.indice
        ,   T2.sts
FROM        tbl1 T1
INNER JOIN  tbl2 T2 ON T2.pessoa_id = T1.pessoa_id
ORDER BY    (   CASE T2.sts 
                WHEN 'ON-LINE'  THEN 1 
                WHEN 'OFF-LINE' THEN 2 
                ELSE 3 
                END
            )
        ,   T2.indice
```

Se por ventura tiver, no futuro, outro tipo de *status*, basta gerir a ordenação adicionando ou alterando os estados (ou a numeração para cada um).

Comment: Tenho 3 Tabelas a Pessoa, Acesso e a Lista
A Lista é apenas uma tabela utilizada para listar todas as pessoas da escala onde em 1 escala posso ter n listas de pessoas
 

Pessoa:
ID, Acesso_id(fk)
Acesso 
Sts 
Lista
Pessoa_Id, indice

Quero ordenar todas as pessoas pelos indices, mas se sts != on line fica no final
Acredito que já tenha me dado uma luz de como fazer com o case no order by, obrigado :D

Answer (score 1):

De forma bem simples basta adicionar a sintaxe a sua consulta:

```
. . .  order by Tabela2.sts, Tabela1.Indice
```